# PostgreSQL date converted to Java Date instead of LocalDate

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, java-time

Using JOOQ 3.10.1, I believe that the `javaTimeTypes` flag is on by default for the code generator.

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database with a `date` column and a `time with time zone` column:

- the `time with time zone` column becomes an `OffsetDateTime` in the record class, as expected.
- the `date` becomes `java.sql.Date` in the record class when I would have expected a `LocalDate`.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Don't know if it will help, but there is something about converters  here, including a `LocalDateConverter` : https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/ .

Comment: That's what I have been using before 3.10 indeed but it should not be necessary any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using JOOQ 3.10.1, I believe that the javaTimeTypes flag is on by default for the code generator.

Here's the specification: https://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.10.0.xsd

```xml
<element name="javaTimeTypes" type="boolean" default="false" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">..
```

So, no, it is not turned on by default.

> the `time with time zone` column becomes an OffsetDateTime in the record class, as expected.

That's because there's no other type that can meaningfully represent the  `time with time zone` data type.

Comment: Mmm - worst bit is probably that I did check the xsd and concluded that it defaulted to true - probably need to ask an optician instead of stackoverflow! All sorted thanks.

Comment: @assylias: Well, now it's documented here as well for future visitors who might not know that the XSD exists :)